# what are the Number of states for the array with 0's and 1's

Tags: arrays, algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

Given an array with just 0's and 1's.

If a `0` is left of a `1` then they swap theirs values

count the number of steps to take all 0's to the right of the array.

**EXAMPLE1**
if array=[0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]

````
[1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]

[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0]

[1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]

[1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]

[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]

the Answer is ```5``` steps.
````

**EXAMPLE2**
if array=[0 1 0 1 0]

```
[1 0 1 0 0]

[1 1 0 0 0]
```

The Answer= `2`

I wrote code to do what is asked. But its very slow for large size of the array :( pls help

Comment: You might want to post your code, so people could try to determine why it's so slow. Please also specify the size for which it's slow. You can [edit] your post to do it.

Comment: Its slow because because the running time is O(n*no.of states) I want a better running time

Comment: I don't know one :|

Comment: @maldanel: Just check the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @maldanel You tried to clarify what you consider a "step" by an example in a comment, but this comment is now deleted. Please [edit] your post to include the relevant info. This will make your question clearer, and help people write answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be best solved using `A* search` with `hamming` like `heuristic` function (we need to prove the heuristic is `admissible`). Here are the steps:

1. For the given array, first compute the `goal` array that we want to reach (simply `sort` the array `descending`).
2. Represent the problem as a (graph) search problem, where the source node is the given array, adjacent nodes are defined to be the arrays that can be obtained by a single `0 1` swap.
3. Push the source node to a `priority queue`, where the priority is defined to be as the `sum` of the distance from the source node (`f(.)`) and heuristic function (`h(.)=hamming distance`) from the goal node. The node in the queue with minimum priority will be popped first, breaking ties arbitrarily.
4. Iteratively pop a node from the priority queue until the `goal` node is reached and push all the adjacent nodes not visited yet to the queue, updating the distance from the source for the popped node.
5. Stop once the `goal` node is popped.

Comment: A* seems like an overkill for this problem. More importantly, what's the gain? The specific problem OP faces is that their (naive) solution is too slow. So, how does A* make for a faster solution, what's the complexity?

Comment: @Gassa A* with a good heuristic should be able to find the goal node fast, by effectively reducing the search space. Since OP has not shared his naive implementation, in case it is uninformative search like bfs, it will blindly explore much more nodes before reaching the target node than that A* will do.

Comment: As I see it, the edges in the graph you suggest have weights 0 or 1. And a vertex of the graph is an array of `n` elements, which will have to be copied every time you add a vertex to the queue. So, if the answer is `X`, it will spend at least `X` * `n` time. Which is already the same as `O(n*no.of states)` mentioned in OP's comment. No gain here?

Comment: Actually, each step is rigorously defined (in the right graph, there is only one edge from the current node to the only possible next node). So, as I see it, graph interpretation does not add value to the solution. You (or I) may have misunderstood what a step is (the way I see it by the example, all `01` substrings in the string are simultaneously changed into `10`).

Comment: I agree with the fact that the simultaneous `01` swaps at a given step is a possibility (in which case there is a single choice only at each step), only thing to think about is whether simultaneous swaps can sometimes takes us further away from the goal node than best (according to min` g(.)+h(.)`) sequential single swaps, I can't find any example immediately though, but can we prove it?

Comment: My understanding of the statement is that it is **given** that each step works this way. Not that we can **choose** which `01` transform to `10`. I agree it is not clear from the question, but this interpretation of the problem statement makes most sense to me. Note that the question doesn't mention being wrong with the naive solution which works this way, it just mentions being slow.

Answer (score -2):

Calculate the waiting time for each 1. now take the waiting time of the last 1 say t1 and add the number of zeros before it say totatlz.

your `answer = t1 + totalz`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define mp make_pair
#define pb push_back
#define vll vector<ll>
#define F first
#define S second
#define pll pair<ll,ll>
#define FOR1(i,a) for(i=0;i<=a;i++)
#define FOR2(i,a,b) for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
#define endl '\n'
#define clr(a) memset(a,0,sizeof(a))
#define all(x) x.begin(),x.end()
typedef long long ll;

int main()
{
    ll t,i;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        ll n,totalz=0,interval=0,k=0,j;
        cin>>n;
        ll asyncTime[n]={0},a[n]={0};
        bool flag=false;
        FOR1(i,n-1)
            cin>>a[i];
        FOR1(i,n-1)
        {
            if(!a[i])
                totalz+=1;
            else
            {
                flag=true;
                asyncTime[k]=0;
                k+=1;
                j=i+1;
                break;
            }
        }
        int l,lastpos;
        FOR2(i,j,n-1)
        {
            if(!a[i])
                totalz+=1,interval+=1;
            else
            {
                if(asyncTime[k-1]>=interval)
                    asyncTime[k]=asyncTime[k-1]-interval+1;
                else
                    asyncTime[k]=0;
                interval=0;
                k+=1;
                lastpos=i;
            }
        }
        // FOR1(i,n-1)
        // cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        // cout<<endl;
        // FOR1(i,k-1)
        // cout<<asyncTime[k]<<" ";
        // cout<<endl;
        if(flag)
        {
            if(asyncTime[k-1]==k-1&&lastpos==k-1)
                cout<<"0"<<endl;
            else
                cout<<asyncTime[k-1]+totalz<<endl;
        }
        else
            cout<<"0"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may work, some basic explanation is lacking: what it does, how fast it does that, and why does this solve the original problem?

Comment: And, it does not even work: it gives 3 instead of 2 to the second given example (`1\n5\n0 1 0 1 0\n`).